# Can I make my own custom grep search tool?

Tags: command-line, nvidia, grep

I was trying to find a particular device on my machine. So I typed in lspci. This gave me a large list of items. Too large to constantly look through to see if my device is still attached or not. So I ran:

```
lspci | grep nvidia
```

This returned nothing. So I tried "Nvidia" and I got nothing and then finally I tried "NVIDIA" and that's when I got a hit.

Grep seems like an awesome tool however it has some obvious limitations. Is it possible to write my own search type function to accomplish this task and include all cases in the string?

If so, would anyone be able to point me in the right direction on learning how to do this. Even if it's some literature I can read on the topic it would be great.

Even if it takes me a month I'd love to learn how to develop my own tool with that functionality.

Thanks.

Comment: Try doing a "man grep" in the terminal to get usage instructions. Grep is a very powerful tool aready. For instance, to do what you are trying to do just add the -i option to make it case insensitive like this: lspci |grep -i nvidia

Comment: Very bad performance compared to `grep`, but this works: `grepi(){ shopt -s nocasematch; while IFS= read line; do [[ "$line" =~ $1 ]] && printf '%s\n' "$line"; done;}` --> `lspci | grepi nvidia`. However, imo, this is a programming question and thus off-topic here.

Answer (score 6):

`man grep` will give you information about how to use grep. The `-i` option will do what you were looking for: ignore case. Thus, a command

```
lspci | grep -i nvidia
```

would have retrieved NVIDIA.

If you want to make your own tool, an easy way is to define an alias:

```
alias 'grep=grep -i'
```

This customized `grep` command will imply the `-i` option each time you run `grep`. After defining the alias, your original command would have worked the way you wanted. No need to further program your own tool.

This alias definition is valid for the current session only. To enable the option permanently, open your `~/.bashrc` file with a text editor and add the `-i` option in the `alias` definition that is there already:

```
alias grep='grep -i --color=auto'
```